# XCM BuyExecution Fail: TooExpensive when transferring Native Token from your parachain to clone parachain

Tags: polkadot, xcm, hrmp, cross-chain

I am setting up the integration tests to transfer Asset from Parachain A to Parachain B (clone Parachain A).

The XCM execution went successfully on Parachain A, the balance was deducted successfully, but Parachain B got a problem receiving tokens. It throws errors on Parachain B at `BuyExecution` with error `xcm::v2::traits::Error::TooExpensive`. There is `Trader` has been set up for fee calculation, also `8_000_000_000_000` in weight but seems I missed something to make it works.

If anyone has experienced the same issues, would really appreciate if you can shed some lights so I can isolate and fix the issue.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the list of XCM instructions that you've constructed?

Comment: Hi @KeithYeung, I did it through orml xtokens transfer, basically, the below XCM instructions have been executed.

`// On parachain A:  WithdrawAsset (Succeeded) => DepositReserveAsset (Succeeded)

 // On parachain B: ReserveAssetDeposited (Succeed) => ClearOrigin (Succeed) => BuyExecution (Failed) => DepositAsset -> Not reach`

Comment: The payment provided (whatever that is) cannot be used to pay for the weight which `BuyExecution` is attempting to purchase. Without seeing the actual XCM instruction, the contents of the Holding register and the specifics of the `Trader` type, it's impossible to describe what you should change to make it work.

Comment: The two issues most likely are: a) the asset which `Trader` is expecting is not the asset which `BuyExecution` is attempting to pay with (perhaps the `MultiLocation` is incorrect?); or b) `Trader` has been configured with an asset-per-weight price which results in more of the asset needed for the weight you're trying to buy than the payment you are attempting to pay for it with.

Comment: Are you using IdentityFee rather than WeightToFee?  Relevant issue: https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/issues/920

Comment: Thanks @Gav for your suggestion. I am looking into these possible issues and trying to isolate them. I will report back on how it goes which may be helpful for other builders in the future.

Comment: Thanks @Squirrel. I looked into it and seems it doesn't cause the issue. I used `FixedRateOfFungible` to calculate fee per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments. Based on the suggestions, I have identified the issue and posted here which may help other Substrate builders in the future.

As mentioned by @Gav, there is a problem with the asset that pay for weight, doing more debugging with this [line](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/xcm/xcm-builder/src/weight.rs#L155.) when `Trader` calculates fee. I found the asset `MultiLocation` is mismatched.

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if you're happy it's solved now.